# Convert Foreach to lambda or LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, linq

How can I convert the ELSE part into single Lambda or LINQ query.

I want to get rid of multiple for/foreach statements. I tried through it through multiple ways but lamda query is not giving me desired result.

For ex: In case response.UResources has no data (i.e. its empty list)

here CurrentBS is List and UResources is List

```
 List<BSS> noTask = new List<BSS>();

 if (response.CurrentBS.Count > 0 && 
     response.UResources != null && 
     response.UResources.Count == 0)
 {
     noTask = response.CurrentBS.Where(x => x.CurrentBS.TaskId == 0).ToList();
 }
 else
 {
     var bnt = response.CurrentBS.Where(x => x.CurrentBS.TaskId == 0).ToList();

     for (int index = bnt.Count() - 1; index >= 0; index--)
     {
         foreach (var uResource in response.UResources)
         {
             if (bnt[index].BotId.ToString().ToLower() == uResource.Name.ToLower()
                 && uResource.Type == ResourceType.Bot)
             {
                 bnt.RemoveAt(index);
             }
         }
     }

     noTask = bnt;
  }
```

Data output should  be in only these two cases

**CASE : 1**

```
List of CurrentBS
BotId | TaskId
101   | 0
102   | 0
103   | 0
104   | 0
105   | 0

List of UResource = empty list
Name | Type

Output should return all items from List of CurrentBS i.e 
101,102,103,104,105
```

**CASE : 2**

```
List of CurrentBS
BotId | TaskId
101   | 0
102   | 0
103   | 0
104   | 17
105   | 14

List of UResource

Name| Type
103 | Bot
104 | Bot 
105 | Bot 

Output should return items 101, 102 from list of CurrentBS
```

**Case 1 is for IF  and CASE 2 is for ELSE**

Can I have a single query for both cases or 2 separate query for if and else.

Comment: `Where` uses loops internally too. The expensive part in your code is `BotId.ToString().ToLower() == uResource.Name.ToLower()`, not the loops. String modifications always generate new strings. You can use case-insensitive comparison using eg `String.Equals(..,StringComoparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to meet your criteria:

```
IEnumerable<BSS> noTask = response.CurrentBS.Where(x => x.CurrentBS.TaskId == 0);

if (response.CurrentBS.Count <= 0 ||
    response.UResources == null ||
    response.UResources.Count != 0)
{
    var badBotNames = response.UResources
        .Where(uResource => uResource.Type == ResourceType.Bot)
        .Select(uResource => uResource.Name)
        .ToHashSet(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    noTask = noTask.Where(x => !badBotNames.Contains(x.BotId.ToString()));
}
```

Benefits:

- `O(n)` algorithm instead of `O(n²)`
- Removes repetitive code
- Doesn't populate a list with a bunch of values only to remove them.
- Avoids unnecessary `ToString()` and `ToLower()`

Oddities that still bother me:

- If `response.UResources` is null, this will throw a null reference exception. Why allow that in the `if`?
- In your sample inputs, BotId and Resource.Name appear to be integers. Why are they not both typed as integers? If they have integer-like string values, why do you convert them to lowercase?

I'd probably simplify the code to something like this, even though it might do a little more work in some cases:

```
IEnumerable<BSS> noTask = response.CurrentBS.Where(x => x.CurrentBS.TaskId == 0);

if (response.UResources.Any())
{
    var badBotNames = response.UResources
        .Where(uResource => uResource.Type == ResourceType.Bot)
        .Select(uResource => uResource.Name)
        .ToHashSet(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    noTask = noTask.Where(x => !badBotNames.Contains(x.BotId.ToString()));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple to just put a `!` around the whole condition and shove it into a `.Where`. The nested `foreach` can go into a `Any`. You can also combine the two sides of the `if`.

Note also that you should do a case-insensitive compare, rather than using `ToLower`.

```cs
var results = response.CurrentBS.Where(x => x.CurrentBS.TaskId == 0);
if (!(response.CurrentBS.Count > 0 && 
     response.UResources != null && 
     response.UResources.Count == 0))
{
    results = results.Where(b =>
        !response.UResources.Any(r =>
            string.Equals(b.BotId.ToString(), uResource.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
            && r.Type == ResourceType.Bot));
}
var noTask = results.ToList();
```

Comment: if response.CurrentBS = 5 items with TaskId=0 and response.UResources has one item with uResource.Name != b.BotId then the result yields no records.
Whereas it should return all records from response.CurrentBS

Comment: According to the logic in your original, you want that to depend on whether there are any matches. So we exclude any case where there are `UResources` which match the `b.BotId`. If that is not what you want then please be clear.

Comment: I have added more information to the main question. Hope that will help.

Comment: The above logic should work for you, I don't understand why you are saying it doesn't work